# How to execute a binary file present in different directory?

Tags: linux, command-line, gcc

I have created a binary executable file using the following command:

```
gcc -o /x/y/file_object /x/z/file_program.c
```

How may I execute `./file_object` without going inside directory `/x/z`?

Comment: why do I need the `.`? why doesn't `./hello-world` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/x/y/file_object
```

This will execute the binary file given its absolute path.

```
alias file_object=/x/y/file_object
```

This will allow you to type `file_object` instead of the whole path.

Comment: why do I need the `.`? why doesn't `./hello-world` work?

Comment: @CharlieParker In the context of this question: `./` is a relative path that refers to something in _this_ directory (the current working directory). If you change the directory with `cd`, you will no longer find whatever it was at that exact relative path. However, the absolute path (starting with `/` and naming all the directories down to what you want to refer to) will always be valid from whichever directory you are currently in. This was the issue in the question that I answered, and the answer was to use that absolute path instead of the path relative to the current directory.